# AJAX doesn't return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've been trying to learn how to use ajax however I can't seem to get any result back.

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="functions.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="foodLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Search For Food Label</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="search" id="foodLabel">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="submit" onclick="getFormData()">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my js file

```
function getFormData(){ 
    var foodLabel=document.getElementById('foodLabel').value;
    var searchURL = buildSearchURL(foodLabel);
    //console.log(searchURL);

    $.ajax({
        url: searchURL,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    });

}

function buildSearchURL(label){
    var searchURL = "http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=" + label + "&sort=n&max=25&offset=0&api_key=h9TKX24GP1vDETSUfQc2hU8b4w3orECoocoQFeE7";
    return searchURL;
}
```

I've tried multiple variations in trying to make this work but all I'm getting is error function back.
Would you be able to help me out here?

If I enter, for example, "chips" into input box, it would generate this URL:
http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=chips&sort=n&max=25&offset=0&api_key=DEMO_KEY

Which would be a valid json (checked)

```
{
    "list": {
        "q": "chips",
        "sr": "28",
        "ds": "any",
        "start": 0,
        "end": 25,
        "total": 5292,
        "group": "",
        "sort": "n",
        "item": [
            {
                "offset": 0,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "ABE'S, MUFFINS, CHOCOLATE CHIP COOKIE, UPC: 044261720574",
                "ndbno": "45167403",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 1,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "ACME FRESH MARKET, KETTLE COOKED POTATO CHIPS, SALT & CRACKED PEPPER, UPC: 036846481505",
                "ndbno": "45155196",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 2,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "A&G, ALL NATURAL VEGGIE CHIPS, UPC: 752423299621",
                "ndbno": "45153673",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 3,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AHOLD, CHEWY GRANOLA BARS, PEANUT BUTTER CHOCOLATE CHIP, UPC: 688267163821",
                "ndbno": "45140163",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 4,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AHOLD, CRUNCHY GRANOLA CHIPS, BUTTER PECAN, UPC: 688267155703",
                "ndbno": "45144989",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 5,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AHOLD, CRUNCHY GRANOLA CHIPS, VANILLA BEAN, UPC: 088267155772",
                "ndbno": "45144990",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 6,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AHOLD, DUNKER COOKIES, WITH CHOCOLATE CHIPS, UPC: 688267151552",
                "ndbno": "45045677",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 7,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AHOLD, GRANOLA CHIPS, HONEY, UPC: 688267155697",
                "ndbno": "45149168",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 8,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AHOLD, LENTIL CHIPS, SEA SALT, UPC: 688267152481",
                "ndbno": "45165684",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 9,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AHOLD, OVAL DILLS HAMBURGER PICKLE CHIPS, UPC: 688267153181",
                "ndbno": "45044318",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 10,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AHOLD, POTATO CHIPS, SOUR CREAM & ONION, UPC: 688267119699",
                "ndbno": "45153253",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 11,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AHOLD, PROTEIN GRANOLA BARS, PEANUT BUTTER & DARK CHOCOLATE CHIPS, UPC: 688267164309",
                "ndbno": "45140175",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 12,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AHOLD, PUMPKIN SEED TORTILLA CHIPS, UPC: 688267157868",
                "ndbno": "45045470",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 13,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AHOLD, RIPPLED POTATO CHIPS, JALAPENO QUESO, UPC: 688267167928",
                "ndbno": "45158187",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 14,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AHOLD, SWEET HORSERADISH PICKLE CHIPS, UPC: 688267136092",
                "ndbno": "45235372",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 15,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AHOLD, WAFFLES, CHOCOLATE CHIP, UPC: 688267150029",
                "ndbno": "45178546",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 16,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AIR POPPED POTATO CHIPS, UPC: 011150224000",
                "ndbno": "45009759",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 17,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AIR POPPED POTATO CHIPS, UPC: 011150224017",
                "ndbno": "45009762",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 18,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AIR POPPED POTATO CHIPS, UPC: 011150224024",
                "ndbno": "45009763",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 19,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "ALBERTSON'S, ICE CREAM, MINT CHIP, UPC: 041163458796",
                "ndbno": "45002572",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 20,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "ALBERTSONS/SAFEWAY, OVEN BAKED COOKIES, CHOCOLATE CHIP, UPC: 022735920392",
                "ndbno": "45162949",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 21,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "ALDEN'S, ICE CREAM, MINT CHIP, UPC: 072609741837",
                "ndbno": "45025020",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 22,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "ALDEN'S, ORGANIC PREMIUM ICE CREAM, COFFEE CHIP, UPC: 072609043528",
                "ndbno": "45184092",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 23,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "ALEIAS, GLUTEN FREE CHOCOLATE CHIP COOKIE, UPC: 855930001500",
                "ndbno": "45066064",
                "ds": "BL"
            },
            {
                "offset": 24,
                "group": "Branded Food Products Database",
                "name": "AL GELATO CHICAGO, GELATO, CHOCOLATE CHIP, UPC: 093959741032",
                "ndbno": "45185128",
                "ds": "BL"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look in the network tab of the chrome inspector to see what's going wrong with the ajax request.

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: What are you seeing when accessing the `searchURL` in your browser?

Comment: when I check inspector, it just says "finished" for js file

Comment: submit button submit. You do not cancel the action so the page submits.

Comment: @user1796741 to be clear... you're specifically getting the "failure" alert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a submit button. The form submits when you click the button. So you need to prevent the form from submitting. What happens now is you have a race condition with the Ajax call and the form submitting. The form submitting wins.

```
onclick="getFormData(); return false;"
```

It would be better to attach the event with jQuery or addEventListener and use preventDefault.

```
$("form").on("submit", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    getFormData();
} );
```

And when you read the value, you need to encode the value

```
var foodLabel = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('foodLabel').value);
```

Comment: does not explain the `error` ajax handler being called

Comment: does not answers the question. making concurrent requests do not relate invoking error callback

Comment: Thanks! I added return false and now can see object received in console menu. Just to be sure I understood the problem. When I clicked submit, it originally reset the page which resulted in dropped session and no object returned?

Comment: @igor Incorrect... the error handler is called when the Ajax call is aborted. Test it out https://jsfiddle.net/3y3doabt/

Comment: @salihşenolçakarcı See my comment above with demo showing it fail

Comment: Just a note @epascarello, your example succeeds in all cases for me (although I agree with your answer, and logic).

Comment: @user1796741 What happens is when the button is clicked you fire off the Ajax call and the form submission. When the form submits, the browser kills off the Ajax call which fires the error event.  Than the page continues to submit the form. In your case, because the form has no action, it submits to itself so it basically reloads the page.

Answer (score 0):

The url works

```
http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=us&sort=n&max=25&offset=0&api_key=h9TKX24GP1vDETSUfQc2hU8b4w3orECoocoQFeE7
```

You may get `""` for label and this below gives error

```
http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=""&sort=n&max=25&offset=0&api_key=h9TKX24GP1vDETSUfQc2hU8b4w3orECoocoQFeE7
```

Comment: value will not be undefined, it can be `""`